# use selectbox to show mysql data in html <li> tag without refreshing page with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to populate mysql table inside ul li tags. I couldn't be success. I don't know how to use jquery to get mysql data.
Can you guys help me please? 
I'm getting my result on getdata.php without any problem. However I couldn't success to show result inside main.php without refreshing page.

main.php

```
 <form name="cnt" id="cnt" action="get_shipping_price.php" method="Post" >
                          <select id="c_list" name="country" style="width:160px;" onChange="this.form.submit()">
            <?php
            $countries = $database->getCountry();
            foreach ($countries as $country) {
                echo '<option value="' . $country['printable_name'] . '" ' . ($req_user_info['country'] == $country['numcode'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . $country['printable_name'] . '</option>';
            }
         ?>
            </select>
            </form>

    <!-- result list box -->
               <div id="result_box">
                   <ul>
                        <li class="blue_heading">A</li>
                            <li class="blue_heading">O / E</li>
                            <li class="blue_heading">I / I</li>
                            <li class="lgray_lis"></li>
                            <li class="lgray_lis"></li>
                            <li class="lgray_lis"></li>
                            <li class="dgray_lis"></li>
                            <li class="dgray_lis"></li>
                            <li class="dgray_lis"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

get_data.php

```
<?php
include("include/database.php");
if(isset($_POST['country']) )
{
  $cnt_id = $_POST['country'];

 $result = $database->select("Select * From zone Where DHL = '$cnt_id' "); 
  foreach ($result as $row) {
   $row['zone'];
  }
}


 $result = $database->select("Select * From price_in_dis");

  foreach ($result as $indis)   
{ 
  if ($row['zone'] == 1)
    {

    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>" .'y'.$indis['A']. "</li>"; 

    echo "</ul>";


  }


   if ($row['zone'] == 2)
     {
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>" .$dis['C']. "</li>" ;
    echo "</ul>";


  }

   if ($row['zone'] == 3)
    {

    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>" .$dis['D']. "</li>" ;
    echo "</ul>";


  }

}
?>
```

Comment: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) Read about it

Comment: You will need [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to do this task

Comment: @itsme I couldnt write to jquery code im stuck in it

Comment: Here is a tutorial. Try googling things before posting questions here http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html

Comment: Providing the Jquery code even if it don't work gives others the chance to understand how much you do know and can then show you where you are going wrong... No-one is going to write it for you (at least not for free :P )

Comment: What's the purpose of that piece of code?`if(isset($_POST['country']) )
{
  $cnt_id = $_POST['country'];

 $result = $database->select("Select * From zone Where DHL = '$cnt_id' "); 
  foreach ($result as $row) {
   $row['zone'];
  }
}
` It doesn't do anything (at least it outputs nothing)

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 options,

- Use a form or something to submit the value.
- Make the Li clickable with with link where you pass through the variable value.
- Use Ajax and Jquery to make some functions on 'click submit this'.  There is a lot of different ways to do this, you can create a hidden form for example. ( I recommended this one only if you add some security in both sides, client and server)

U'll need a php file anyway the different is how you pass the parameter.